# Google Maps iFrame not loading when using javascript variables on "src"

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, iframe

I have an html file with javascript used to get the exif data out of an image, more specifically GPS latitude and longitude.

That data is the converted to a format readable by a Google Maps iFrame to then show where that photo was taken...

The problem I'm having at the moment is on the use of JavaScript variables that contain the values of the latitude and longitude on the "src" of the iFrame.

If I use the specific values on the source, the iFrame loads correctly on that specific location... but if I replace them with the variables that DO have the same exact values, nothing loads... the iFrame stays blank.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>EXIF</title>
    <style>
        img{
            width: 500px;
            max-height: auto;
        }   
    </style>    
</head>

<body>

    <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4867/30883801817_bf122bc498_o.jpg" id="img1" />

    <iframe id="mapa_google" src="" width="640" height="480"></iframe>


    <h1>Latitude Exif</h1>
    <p id="local_lat"></p>

    <h1>Longitude Exif</h1>
    <p id="local_lon"></p>

    <h1>Latitude Final</h1>
    <p id="local_lat_final"></p>

    <h1>Longitude Final</h1>
    <p id="local_lon_final"></p>

    <script src="exif.js"></script>

    <script>

        var toDecimal = function (number) {


            var d = Math.floor(number[0]);
            var m = Math.floor(number[1]);
            var s = ((number[1]%1)*60);

            var dms= d+(m/60)+(s/3600);

            return dms

        };


        window.onload=getExif;

        function getExif() {
            img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
            EXIF.getData(img1, function() {

            latitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLatitude");
            longitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLongitude");  

            local_lat = document.getElementById("local_lat");
            local_lon = document.getElementById("local_lon");

            local_lat.innerHTML = `${latitude}`;
            local_lon.innerHTML = `${longitude}`;


            latitude_final = toDecimal(latitude);
            local_lat_final = document.getElementById("local_lat_final");
            local_lat_final.innerHTML = `${latitude_final}`;

            longitude_final = toDecimal(longitude);
            local_lon_final = document.getElementById("local_lon_final");
            local_lon_final.innerHTML = `${longitude_final}`;   

            });

        }

        getExif();

        document.getElementById("mapa_google").src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDQSbRMCIv1gDsT2qRsY8HvLyZP11hte_Y&q="+latitude_final+"+"+longitude_final;    

        /* IF I USE THE CODE BELOW WITH THE SPECIFIC LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE, THE iFrame works perfectly but id I use the one above, with the variables that contain those same values, nothing loads on that iFrame... it stays blank*/

        document.getElementById("mapa_google").src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDQSbRMCIv1gDsT2qRsY8HvLyZP11hte_Y&q=41.38448666666667+2.1066883333333335";


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getExif()` function is asynchronous.  You need to use the results of the asynchronous load of the `<img>` inside the callback function, once the image has loaded.

```
function getExif() {
  img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
  EXIF.getData(img1, function() {

    latitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLatitude");
    longitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLongitude");

    local_lat = document.getElementById("local_lat");
    local_lon = document.getElementById("local_lon");

    local_lat.innerHTML = `${latitude}`;
    local_lon.innerHTML = `${longitude}`;

    latitude_final = toDecimal(latitude);
    local_lat_final = document.getElementById("local_lat_final");
    local_lat_final.innerHTML = `${latitude_final}`;

    longitude_final = toDecimal(longitude);
    local_lon_final = document.getElementById("local_lon_final");
    local_lon_final.innerHTML = `${longitude_final}`;
    document.getElementById("mapa_google").src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDQSbRMCIv1gDsT2qRsY8HvLyZP11hte_Y&q=" + latitude_final + "+" + longitude_final;

});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5nazfj4r/2/)

**code snippet:**

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  max-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/exif-js/exif-js@2.3.0/exif.js"></script>
<img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4867/30883801817_bf122bc498_o.jpg" id="img1" onload="getExif();" />

<iframe id="mapa_google" src="" width="640" height="480"></iframe>


<h1>Latitude Exif</h1>
<p id="local_lat"></p>

<h1>Longitude Exif</h1>
<p id="local_lon"></p>

<h1>Latitude Final</h1>
<p id="local_lat_final"></p>

<h1>Longitude Final</h1>
<p id="local_lon_final"></p>

<script>
  var toDecimal = function(number) {


    var d = Math.floor(number[0]);
    var m = Math.floor(number[1]);
    var s = ((number[1] % 1) * 60);

    var dms = d + (m / 60) + (s / 3600);

    return dms

  };


  // window.onload = getExif;

  function getExif() {
    img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    EXIF.getData(img1, function() {

      latitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLatitude");
      longitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLongitude");

      local_lat = document.getElementById("local_lat");
      local_lon = document.getElementById("local_lon");

      local_lat.innerHTML = `${latitude}`;
      local_lon.innerHTML = `${longitude}`;


      latitude_final = toDecimal(latitude);
      local_lat_final = document.getElementById("local_lat_final");
      local_lat_final.innerHTML = `${latitude_final}`;

      longitude_final = toDecimal(longitude);
      local_lon_final = document.getElementById("local_lon_final");
      local_lon_final.innerHTML = `${longitude_final}`;
      document.getElementById("mapa_google").src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDQSbRMCIv1gDsT2qRsY8HvLyZP11hte_Y&q=" + latitude_final + "+" + longitude_final;

    });

  }

  // getExif();
</script>
```